# Formula links hijacking workbook even though disabled by VBA and in workbook

Tags: excel, vba

**Issue summary:**

I'm trying to understand why Excel asks for a linked workbook path even though that book has been opened by a macro and link updates are turned off.

"Workbook 1" is a tracker; "Workbook 2" carries common data (e.g. contact details). Formulae pull data from 2 to 1; a macro in Workbook 1 opens Workbook 2 to ensure links are updated and current.

Excel stops and asks the user to identify the path of Workbook 2 even though:

- It's been opened by the macro on startup
- automatic update is turned off
- the macro specifies to not update links
- path to the workbook is correct

There are hundreds of formulae so the user gets stuck being asked repeatedly  to identify Workbook 2 and has to Ctrl=Alt=Delete out

**I have tried..**

- I've checked the drive paths on user computers are same
- I've turned off the 'auto-update' option in Excel (File > Edit Links to Files > Startup Prompt > "Don't display the alert and don't update links"

**On-Open event code**

*HF_name* is the filename e.g. HF.xlsx

*HF_path* is the full drive path

This code is checking if file is already open (it's very commonly used, and a large file) and if not it finds and opens it.

```vb
For Each wBook In Application.Workbooks
  If wBook.Name = HF_name Then
    flag = 1
  End If
Next wBook

If flag = 0 Then
  'HF not found; Open HF
  'If open fails then warn the user that the list cannot be updated

  On Error GoTo error_couldNotOpenHF
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Set HF = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=HF_path, UpdateLinks:=False, 
        ReadOnly:=True, ignoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Else
  Set HF = Workbooks(HF_name)
End If

Calculate
```

What I expect is;

1. Workbook 1 opens Workbook 2 with macro; no link update happens
2. As workbook 2 is the path for the links, Excel will default from "DRIVE\folder\Folder\MSF.xlsx  ..." to just "MSF.xlsx.." as it does when your linked workbook is open
3. The code does 'Calculate' to force a re-calc when Workbook 2 is already open, so links should update then.

Comment: Are you certain it works that way - i.e. can you confirm assumptions 2 and 3 manually?

Comment: I thought I had but I've re-tried it and it seems that even if you have "Don't show.. don't update" open, as soon as you open the workbook linked to the primary workbook is updated outwith your control.  Same happens whether you open with a macro or not.  Doesn't explain though why it'd ask for the file linked-to to be identified if it's already open..